# Callback is not obtained at onAdLoaded

Tags: android, admob

Iam trying to display ad using Admob,but Iam not getting any call at onAdloaded.Can someone help...
  Iam displaying an inerstitial ad.Iam setting and then Iam trying to load it...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);       
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(getString(R.string.font_alegreya_sans_regular));
    setInterstitialAd();
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_activity);
}

private void setInterstitialAd() {
    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(INTERSTITIAL_AD_ID);

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

        }
```

});
    }

```
private void initAdView() {
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_container_layout);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that onAdLoaded() is not called? Could you check the logcat output? Admob logs it when it finishes loading the ad. You could also add your own log in the onAdLoaded just to be sure. Obviously you'll also need an internet connection & have the android permissions for internet access. Also, where is this displayInterstitial() method?

Answer (score 0):

You should'nt have displayInterstitial() inside onAdLoaded(). This is causing the outcome of Ad not being shown. Either show an Ad after some level or user made action like after five level, one is displaying an interstitial, it comes in the pause menu. you keep it loaded from before and display it on the fifth level. or you can have it in that pause menu after some amount of time using a timer ( in which displayInterstitial() ) is included.

Comment: Not really. If you really want to then you can display the interstitial as soon as it is loaded. For user-experience it is most likely not the best solution, but technically it is obviously possible.

Comment: it is not working for him, this is why he asked on stackoverflow. He says that way Ad is not displaying.  I tried it before and it doesn't work. It only works by the way described in official google tutorial which doesn't ask for any condition of onAdLoaded before calling displayInterstitial(). Because inside displayInterstitial(), it is already checking if   if (interstitial.isLoaded()) . So please verify stuff before being too obvious and technical.

Comment: And btw @suraj you got the displayInterstitial() class correctly from here- https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial

Comment: Just verified it ;-) If I do `mInterstitial.show();` inside AdListener's `onAdLoaded()` method in my sample project then it shows the interstitial right after the ad got loaded. Any further doubts?

Comment: @donfuxx Yes, it can be done. But it provides poor user experience and Admob has indicated that it is likely to get your account banned. So please don't encourage people to follow this *really* poor coding practice.

Comment: @William Yes, I agree with that. That is why I mentioned the user-experience issue in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suraj, add some log into both callback methods. One of them will be called. 
I suspect the ad request is failing for reason, so `onFailedToLoad()` will be getting called instead.

Also **DON'T** call `displayInterstitial()` from `onAdLoaded()`. This causes really poor user experience and is likely to get your Admob account banned.